# Adding title tags to each image in the grid view using ngx-crystal-gallary

Tags: angular, ngx-gallery

Is there a way to add title tags to each image in the grid view using **[ngx-crystal-gallary](https://github.com/drozhzhin-n-e/ngx-crystal-gallery)**

```
 <crystal-gallery [images]="selectedFolder.imageUrlsWithPreview" [config]="myConfig">
  </crystal-gallery>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please atach part of your code and clearify what exaclty you want and how did you tried to solve it

Comment: one title for each image, or multiple tags for each image?

Comment: One title tag for each image

Comment: the `description: 'title of the image'` property should do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
myImages = [
    {
        preview: 'path_to_preview',
        full: 'path_to_full_image',
        width: natural_width, // used for masonry
        height: natural_height // used for masonry
        description: '<description/title of the image>' // optional property
    },
    ...
myConfig = {
    ...
};
];
```

```html
<crystal-gallery [images]="myImages" [config]="myConfig"></crystal-gallery>
```

**result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

for your partical usecase, ngx-crystal-gallery doesn't support titles on the images grid.

**alternative**:
use [ng-image-slider](https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider)

Comment: I want this title tag to be in the grid view not in the lightbox

Comment: that's not supported by the library based on their documentation, you can use instead this: https://github.com/sanjayV/ng-image-slider

Comment: it's more active than ngx-crystal-gallery (3years vs 6 months for the last commit)